# Site down after failed Gantry upgrade (Joomla)

Tags: joomla, backend

I have a Joomla site that i would like to update to version 2.5, but before I did that I upgrade the Gantry framework. Big mistake. The template is from Rocket Theme, [Camber](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla/camber/).

I updated Gantry via extension manager. The installation was canceled and now I get an error message. I can not access my page or backend.

What can I do?!

My current Joomla is 1.7
My URL: [www.casabar.com](http://www.casabar.com)

Error code:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getWord() on a non-object in /libraries/gantry/gantry.php on line 189
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you take an update of the site before you do the backup. THE number 1 rule of all updates. Then you could always have double backed. Try downloading the old gantry version you were using and replace the gantry folder in the libraries folder with the old version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You mention the installation was cancelled - try uninstall the extension from the extension manager and then re-install it successfully?

It sounds as if one of the dependent files was not copied as the installation was interrupted?

-- UPDATE

Oh I see you cant access the backend. In this case, I would suggest a FTP upload of the gantry files.